# Autogenerating constructors which just initialize the fields to the passed params?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation

is there some way to autogenerate the obvious 2-param constructor for this class in visual studio?

```
class Thing {
  public readonly string a;
  public readonly Object b;
}
```

I guess you're supposed to use the:

```
new Thing { a = ..., b = ... }
```

syntax in such cases, but that won't work with readonly fields as above. Another plus of having a constructor is that you can't forget a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html) supports this functionality. You choose the "generate constructor", pick the fields you want included and you've got your constructor.

Comment: Chose this as an answer because it is what I ended up doing, though the other suggestions are good too :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for a post that's not helpful at all, but I just couldn't resist.

I'm afraid that by using things like T4 templates, you'll (probably) lose IntelliSense, which may not be a price you wanted to pay. You could probably write a VS.NET macro to auto-generate code of the constructor (I believe the code model should give you enough information to do that).

Now, here is the useless part of the post - perhaps you could try another .NET language if you're annoyed with the unnecesary verbosity of C#. In F#, you can write implicit constructors and their parameters automatically become (readonly) fields:

```
type Thing(a:string, b:Object) = 
  // members can use 'a' and 'b' directly - here is one example:
  member this.GetInfo() = 
    "Some info: " + a + (b.ToString())
```

In a real-world scenario, you probably wouldn't need to specify the types, because F# could infer them automatically based on the later usage. Experimenting with F# isn't as difficult if you're already familiar with .NET libraries.

Comment: Sorry for the Wall Of Text here; somehow paragraphs are ignored here.

You hit the nail on the head, I like functional programming ;) Haskell gave me the habit to make just about everything that isn't performance-critical readonly. 


Haven't looked at F# yet, but maybe I should find out whether F# would be acceptable for the people I'm coding for (I guess the worry would be the same as with Haskell, though maybe less severe: That they won't find other programmers who speak it).


C# isn't all that bad FP-wise, though I'm missing sum types.

Comment: there are various free products which provide intellisense for T4. e.g. Tangible Engineering's T4 Editor

Comment: @FunctorSalad: When I saw your nickname, I was expecting that you know Haskell :-). I guess my answer may be useful to others who are still living mostly in the C# world and come across this question. I agree that C# has a lot of functional powers (afterall, I wrote a book about functional programming in C# and F#). Sum types and pattern matching would be certainly nice.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at T4 templates. It would be fairly simple to write a template which iterates a list of the readonly property names and types and creates the necessary code for the properties and constructor.

T4 templates are built into Visual Studio. Check out Scott Hanselman's [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) about T4 templates for more detail.

There are other products which can automate this kind of refactoring. Resharper is one of these, but it is not free.